# Magmi 0.7.22 won't properly import and index url keys in Magento EE 1.13.1

Tags: magmi

I cannot find a concrete answer after an exhaustive search and I really need an answer to this question:

Does Magmi 0.7.22 support url key imports into EE 1.13.1?

On older Magmi versions, it would not import the url key into the proper table for EE url keys:

catalog_product_entity_url_key
catalog_url_rewrite_product_cl

The only place I could find the url key was in admin, and that was due to the fact it was in the catalog_product_entity_varchar table, which makes sense.

But, when I reindex, the entry is not created in enterprise_url_rewrite. Perplexing b/c the entry in cl should trigger that, although I had tested this before by adding the record directly into the catalog_product_entity_url_key, again seeing the similar entry into the cl table, reindexing, but the same lack of entry into enterprise_url_rewrite.

Lastly, I see the update on GIThub on the "fix for url key unique index":

https://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/git/ci/8f3efc48140e4205350c92ece3526d04748fc713/

I did change this file in my .22 install and tried again, still no luck.

I have 0.7.22 installed, and downloaded the complete zip for 0.7.23 from the master GIT. I haven't installed that yet, but (and pardon my ignorance here) would I just upload all the files in the .23 Magmi folder over the installed .22 files on my installation? Would you recommend .23? No one really seems to speak to this.

Thanks so much in advance for your help with this issue.

Kory

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. It works. If it doesn't work, which it didn't in my test environment, but did in my live, flush the enterprice_url_rewrite table and run the indexes.

That makes it work.